# Weird Ubuntu 11.10 GUI problem

Tags: 11.10, unity, gui, gtk3

It sounds different from the normal unity theme, how to correct it?

Why are the images changed?

It happens even though I have booted few times.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like gnome-setting-daemon is not running or is hanged.

To solve it just open a terminal and type

```
killall gnome-settings-daemon
gnome-settings-daemon
```

The first line should kill any instance of gnome-settings-daemon that is running, just in case. The second line should launch it.

If this works, we know the problem and a workaround, now we still have to discover why it isn't running.